# JQuery works in Chrome and IE and doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have this code:

```
function addComment(cmId){
  var val = document.getElementById("wac"+cmId).value;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("index.php?s=comments", {addcomment_id: cmId, commentname: val}, function(){
      $("#cs"+cmId).load("index.php?s=ajaxcomments&id="+cmId);
    });  
  });
}
```

It works in Chrome and IE but when I try it in Firefox nothing seems to work. Console has no errors. With or without $(document).ready it's the same thing.

**EDIT:**

The html code:

```
<form class="comment_form" onsubmit="addComment(13)">
    <textarea rows="1" cols="10" id="wac13" class="write_a_comment" type="text" style="width: 145px;" placeholder="Write a comment!" name="commentname"></textarea>&nbsp;
    <input id="comment_submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: What console / Firebug debugging have you done in the Firefox failure case? In particular in the Network activity tab -- is the index.php script actually called dynamically and what does it return?

Comment: You could also throw "debugger;" right inside the function to make sure it's getting called and then step through to see what your values are. Definitely try some debugging steps.

Comment: i tried debuggin too. it went into the jquery library but when it reloaded the page nothing happened again

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML that goes along with this.  How is this function being called?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: some functional comments: `<center>` [no longer exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center); don't use it, just use CSS if you need content centered. Secondly, you're showing PHP code while asking about jQuery, so take PHP out of the equation: use straight up `onsubmit="addComment(...)"` with an already real id in there, for testing purposes (and the same for that textarea of course. Turn that HTML into pure HTML)